# How to format the current date and time to include which timezone?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to get the current date and time in the following format:

```
2017-12-27T15:20:11+05:30
```

How do I do it ?

If I do:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now.isoformat()
```

Then it comes out like this:

```
2014-09-26T16:34:40.278298
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a timezone aware datetime:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()
'2017-12-28T05:22:22.759548+00:00'
```

If you don't want sub-second accuracy:

```
>>> datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
'2017-12-28T05:23:11+0000'
```